# how can I fadeOut a Parent?

Tags: jquery, filter, parent, fadeout

This is what I've got so far.

-HTML-

```
  <div id='parent'>
    <h3>Header</h3>
    <p>Body Copy</p>
    </div>
```

-Script-

```
$("#b_submit").click(function() {

    var filter_text = $('input:text').val();

    $('h3:contains('+filter_text+')').fadeOut();

});
```

I need to use this script to fade out the parent of the h3.

Comment: `$('#parent').fadeOut('slow');` ID's are unique, so just target that ?

Comment: I don't see a `#b_submit` or `$('input:text')` in your example.

Comment: is there only a single textbox in your page? As your filter_text is fetching values via elemnt type, not ID or class.. This can cause serious problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fade the parent out with any of these:

```
$('h3:contains('+filter_text+')').parent().fadeOut('slow);
```

or

```
$('#parent').fadeOut('slow');
```

or

```
$('h3:contains('+filter_text+')').closest('div').fadeOut('slow);
```

The `closest()` starts by trying to match the `h3` element itself, and traversing up the DOM tree until it finds the next matching element. If you considered the below structure:

```
<div class="first-level">
    <div class="second-level">
        <h3>Header</h3>
        <p>Body Copy</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

You could use `closest()` to target the `.first-level`:

```
$('h3:contains('+filter_text+')').closest('.first-level').fadeOut('slow);
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question, You need this..

```
$("#b_submit").click(function() {

    var filter_text = $('input:text').val();

    $('h3:contains('+filter_text+')').parent().fadeOut();

});
```